# sass like interpolation in material ui to get BEM like classnames

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, bem

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  block: {

   `${&}__element `: {
      color: 'green',
    }
  },
});
```

the above code doesn't work in material UI. Is there any way to interpolate the `parent selector '&'` to get classname `block__element` just like `sass`'s interpolation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any special syntax around it. `&` by itself will be replaced by `.classNameGeneratedForBlock`, so you can do the following:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  block: {
    "&__element": {
      color: "green"
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a full working example:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  block: {
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
    "&__element": {
      color: "green"
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.block}>
      <h1 className={`${classes.block}__element`}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit optimistic-leftpad-nkkh7]

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  I was missing the ``${classes.block}__element`` part of the puzzle.